# angular 2 ngif not working even though function return true

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

I'm using Angular 2. I have an array and I am looping through each item and setting a boolean. I'm console logging to make sure it's being set properly.  However when I use this function against an `*ngif` it doesn't work. What crucial piece am I missing here?

template:

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of viewableItems>
        <div class="thermometerMercury" *ngIf="showThermometer"></div>
 </div>
```

.ts

```
  processedItems: Item[] = [];
  showThermometer: boolean;

  checkDonation() {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.processedItems.length; i++) {
          let out = this.processedItems[i];
      if (out.isDonation && out.donationAmountDonatedByClient === 0) {
        this.showThermometer = true;
      } else {
        this.showThermometer = false;
      }
      console.log(i, this.showThermometer);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I don't see any `*ngIf` in your posted code

Comment: I think you want to use `[class.thermometerMercury]=showThermometer `, your code only adds the class "thermometerMercury" without any statements.

Comment: I've edited the snippet to reflect my template more accurately

Comment: Is this is just a piece of your code...? Since you have nothing inside your div, so what do expect to happen?¨

Comment: @AJT_82 yes this is just a piece.  If the showThermometer returns true then I want the div with the class thermometer to display otherwise not

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngIf ="showThermometer"></div>
```

Comment: Is that function in OnInit(). because by default showThermometer is false.

Comment: Yes it's inside an `ngOnInit()`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the issue:
1) processedItems is an array, which is being processed and getting validated each object.
2) showThermometer is not specific to Object(s) of array and it looks global.
3) Even showThermometer is true for object 1, there is chance of changing the value as false by object 2 ( when the condition is not satified )
4) The same variable is using by *ngFor

So, changes would be like below:

mplate:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of processedItems>
        <div class="thermometerMercury" *ngIf="item.showThermometer"></div>
 </div>
```

.ts

```
processedItems: Item[] = [];

  checkDonation() {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.processedItems.length; i++) {
          let out = this.processedItems[i];
      if (out.isDonation && out.donationAmountDonatedByClient === 0) {
        out.showThermometer = true;
      } else {
        out.showThermometer = false;
      }
      console.log(i, out.showThermometer);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

template:

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of viewableItems>
        <div class="thermometerMercury" *ngIf="item.showThermometer"></div>
 </div>
```

.ts

```
  processedItems: Item[] = [];
  showThermometer: boolean;

  checkDonation() {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.processedItems.length; i++) {
         let out = this.processedItems[i];
         this.showThermometer = false;
         if (out.isDonation && out.donationAmountDonatedByClient === 0)
         {
           this.showThermometer = true;
         }
         out['showThermometer'] = this.showThermometer;
         console.log(i, this.showThermometer);
       }
   }
```